# Selecting next related row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a spatial dataset in MySQL 5.7 where I have the columns: id, deviceid, latlng_point, time. latlng_point is a geospatial Point.

What I'm trying to achieve is calculating distance from points. I'm unsure on how to approach this.

```
SELECT
    ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(latlng_point, i want the next latlng_point here) AS distance
FROM points
WHERE deviceid = 1
ORDER BY time DESC;
```

In PHP I would do something like this:

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db);

    $query = "SELECT latlng_point FROM points WHERE deviceid = 1...";

    $latlng_array = array();        
    if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $latlng_array[] = $row;
        }
    }

    $distance = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($latlng_array) - 1; $i++) {
        $pt1 = $latlng_array[$i]['latlng_point'];
        $pt2 = $latlng_array[$i+1]['latlng_point'];

        $distance += haversine_function($pt1,$pt2);
    }
    echo "Distance: {$distance}";
?>
```

I'm trying to achieve something similar purely in MySQL.

Comment: What is `next_latlng_point` supposed to be?

Comment: It would be the next latlng related to the deviceid when ordered... but I am unsure how to approach.

Comment: Edit your question rather than answer in comments to make the question clearer. What is the schema of your table? How are the two rows related? What do you mean by _"next latlng related to the deviceid when ordered"_?

Comment: So you have a device (defined by `deviceid`) which is moved from point to point. And you want the overall distance the device has been moved, Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT SUM(ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(p1.latlng_point, p2.latlng_point)) AS total_distance
FROM points p1
JOIN points p2 ON p2.id = (
    SELECT p.id
    FROM points p
    WHERE p.deviceid = p1.deviceid
      AND p.time > p1.time
    ORDER BY p.time ASC
    LIMIT 1
)
WHERE p1.deviceid = 1
```

The (correlated) subquery should return the `id` of the next point (sorted by time).

I can't tell you if it is really efficient or if it even works at all (can't test it).

However you should have an index on `(deviceid, time)` - Assuming that `id` is the primary key.